# Error a la hora de enlazar sql server y a un proyecto en netbeans 6.9

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, netbeans

cuando quiero probrar mi proycto me da un error que es el siguiente:

**java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysqlserver://localhost/bd1**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el codigo para el driver es:

```
private void cargarDriver(){
            try{
                 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            }catch(Exception ex){
                setTitle(ex.toString());
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese driver [necesita Java8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html) y veo que usas 1.6.

Comment: Pero cuando veo mi version de java me aparece: version de java 8. Dame mas soluciones si se te ocurre algo porfavor

Comment: Tu imagen dice JDK 1.6.

Comment: osea que entonces no es la version de java que se ve en acerca de java? y porfa tenme paciencia que soy nuevo en esto de la programacion y en el foro jajaj

Comment: el jdk es 1.6 y el jdbc es 8.0, actualiza el jdk

Comment: Te estás conectando a SQL Server o MySQL? Son dos productos distintos.

Comment: al sql server que es para mi proyecto para enlazar con mi base de datos de phpmyadmin

Comment: chicos me acabe de descargar el jdk-8u111-nb-8-2 de la pagina de apache creen que me va a servir?

Comment: Listo gente, solucionado, como dijeron necesitaba actualizar el jdk